# Redux, React, MapStateToProps: Retrieve a specific element in an array from the redux state tree

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux

I have a reducer named "leagues" in the redux state tree, which is just an array of individual league objects. Each league has a unique id (assigned in the backend), and a name.

I'm trying to write a Component that represents an individual league, and so I want to have a mapStateToProps function that retrieves the correct league. The correct league is known from the url, that is, through the match prop in react-router-v4.

I tried:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        league: state.leagues.find(aLeague => aLeague.id === ownProps.match.params.id)
    }
}
```

But that led to an error "state.leagues.find" is not a function.

Then I tried

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        league: state.leagues[ownProps.match.params.id]
    }
}
```

which doesn't error, but retrieves the wrong league - if the id is 3, then this retrieves state.leagues[3], instead of state.leagues.where(league.id === 3)

The value of leagues when I attempt to access the a single league's page:

```
leagues: [
    {
      id: 54,
      name: 'Test League'
    },
    {
      id: 55,
      name: 'Another Test'
    }
  ],
```

And the leagues reducer code:

```
const initialState = {
  leagues: []
};

export default (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SET_USER_LEAGUES:
      return state = action.leagues
    case ADD_USER_LEAGUE:
    return [
      ...state,
      {
        id: action.league.id,
        name: action.league.name,
      }
    ];
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `state.leagues` when `find` is not found?  What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using chrome

Comment: Can you post the code for your leagues reducer? I would also suggest you have another "league" reducer so you don't have to maintain this logic in your component. It seems like when your component first renders, it's null and causes the app to crash. Set your initial state for your leagues reducer to an empty array.

Comment: posted the code, and I do initialize it to an empty array

Comment: Which action is being dispatch to set the value of a league/leagues?

Comment: `state` is immutable, doing `return state = action.leagues` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @KurtisHardy, the action is an async request to the backend requesting all the leagues that a user belongs to. It is called when the sidebar mounts.

Comment: @FisNaN why not? It simply returns a new copy of state, which is equal to action.leagues, which is itself an array of leagues

Comment: @NathanLauer As my understanding, `return state = action.leagues` is same as `state = action.leagues; return state;` But the state is immutable in the first place. Correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hmm well when I dispatch that action it does set the redux state equal to an array of leagues retrieved from the backend. I’ve confirmed that with the chrome extension redux dev tools

Comment: @NathanLauer does it set the state to an _array of leagues_ or an _object with a league array inside it_? Your initial state is the latter and it looks like the action takes the former. Its doesn't matter which way you choose as long as its the same and this way you wouldn't need the `componentDidMount` function. Let me know if you happy with the life cycle method and I'll be quiet. :-). Also bear in mind that `find` returns undefined if no items are found.

Comment: @KurtisHardy you are correct about the initial state being an array within an object, which did make a difference. I switched to only an array, and that has worked just fine. I’m quite happy with having the logic in a lifecycle method, I think that makes a lot of sense, since I can check the redux store to see if the relevant league is there, and if not, make a new asynchronous request to fetch it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when the redux store is initialized you most likely are setting the initial state to `null` which is why you get an error `state.leagues.find` is not a function and once the state is resolved through an async ajax call then the state is there. I recommend to make that kind of logic in a react lifecycle method like `componentDidMount` and set the state there for the league once the leagues state is available. like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { leagues } = this.state;
  if (leagues && leagues.length > 0) {
    // update the state to the correct league here and this.props.id is the id that you want
    const league = leagues.find(aLeague => aLeague.id === this.props.id);
    this.setState({
      league
    }
  }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: something like - in mapStateProps, just return all leagues, then in componentWillMount find the relevant league, and set the state for the component?

Comment: Yes @NathanLauer and you will need to make sure you check
`if (this.state.leagues.length > 0)` before finding it and updating the state.

Comment: You can also initialize the state in the reducer so `leagues` is an empty list to start with. But this is the best answer here IMO.

Comment: I am setting the initial state to an empty array though

Comment: @NathanLauer even with it set to an empty array it still has to get initialized first to get set to the empty array and might not be ready when you trying to access the state. That's why this type of logic doesn't belong in the `mapStateToProps` function IMO it belongs in a life cycle method.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense

Comment: @Amir5000 How do I wait for the redux state to become available?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like when your component first renders, its default state has been set to null and causes the app to crash when you try to use array method `find` on a null object. Set your initial state for your leagues reducer to an empty array.

Then if your array is empty, your app probably hasn't retrieved results yet, and you can display a message like "Loading...".

However, this doesn't solve the problem of you actually have 0 items in your database, for example. Then you'll show falsely show loading even when there is 0 records.

For that, I would also suggest adding a isLoading reducer (with default state `true`), that maintains the state of your application during the time it is fetching async data. When your async calls complete, dispatch an action to update the appstate and set isLoading to false. Only then should you try to retrieve values from your leagues reducer.

I would also suggest you have another "league" reducer that does the filtering so you don't have to maintain this logic in your component.

Comment: I am setting the initial state to an empty array though

Answer (score 0):

I see that [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is not supported in IE.  So, there could be a browser compatibility issue.

You can always use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead (assuming that `state.leagues` will always be an `Array`:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    const { leagues = [] } = state;
    return {
        league: leagues.filter(aLeague => aLeague.id === ownProps.match.params.id)[0]
    }
}
```

Comment: So I tried that, and I got an error "state.leagues.filter" is not a function

Comment: hmm, I tried that, and now I'm just getting "leagues.filter" is not a function

Comment: I think it might have to do with @Amir5000 answer? I am actually initializing that reducer to null, and then setting it through an async ajax call

Comment: what is the value of `leagues`?

Comment: leagues: [
    {
      id: 54,
      name: 'Test League'
    },
    {
      id: 55,
      name: 'Another Test'
    }
  ],

Comment: I'm stumpted :), problem must be elsewhere

Comment: Thanks for trying anyways! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer looks wrong to me. Could you try this:

```
export default (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_USER_LEAGUES:
            return {
                ...state,
                leagues: action.leagues,
            };
        case ADD_USER_LEAGUE:
            const leagues = [...state.leagues, { id: action.league.id, name: action.league.name, }];
            return {
                ...state,
                leagues,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Some of your functions are manipulating the state and changing between returning a bool, an object and an array.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, I now use an object instead of an array. (See reference 1 below for the reason). And I render the component after the store state is loaded so I can use mapStateToProps. I've put some code extracts below from working code. Hopefully also provides some tips on how to use Redux reducers for this use case. Please excuse any typos, I edited the code extracts inline here.

Store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import * as reducers from './reducers'
const initialState = {
  items: {
    /* id(1): {id: PropTypes.number.isRequired, name: PropTypes.string}
       id(n): {id: PropTypes.number.isRequired, name: PropTypes.string} */
  }
}
var rootReducer = combineReducers(reducers)
window.store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware))
```

Action

```
export const UPDATE_ITEM = 'UPDATE_ITEM'
export const updateItem = item => ({
  type: UPDATE_ITEM,
  item
})
```

Reducer

```
import { UPDATE_ITEM } from './actions'
export const items = (state = null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_ITEM:
      let id = action.item.id
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        [id]: Object.assign({}, state[id], action.item)
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Add some objects to the store

```
import { updateItem } from './actions'
var item1 = {id: 1, name: 'Alice'}
window.store.dispatch(updateItem(item1))
var item2 = {id: 2, name: 'Bob'}
window.store.dispatch(updateItem(item2))
```

SomeComponent mapStateToProps

```
function mapStateToProps (state, ownProps) {
  return {
    item: state.items[ownProps.id]
  }
}
```

Load Component like this after the store is populated.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={window.store}>
    <SomeComponent id={1} />
    <SomeComponent id={2} />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Just wanted to note that my main motivation to solve this was that I was mapping the entire object state (state.items) to props, but then render was called after an update to any array element which was horrible for performance.

References:

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/36031765/1550587