# updating item in redux state causing infinite loop / browser lockdown

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

**EXPECTED OUTCOME:** I'm trying to update a value on my redux state

**ISSUE:** I'm ending up with an infinite loop / browser locking down. I've read [this 'SO' post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031590/right-way-to-update-state-in-redux-reducers#36031765) and the [docs](https://redux.js.org/advanced/exampleredditapi) but struggling to see where I'm going wrong.

This is my state:

```
{ id: 0, product: TV, saleItem: false },
{ id: 1, product: Fridge, saleItem: false }
```

and I want to update it to

```
{ id: 0, product: TV, saleItem: true }
{ id: 1, product: Fridge, saleItem: false }
```

my url is: localhost:4200/#/0

I'm using a selector to get all the items within my store, check the url params and return the item in the state. The above url will return `{ id: 0, product: TV, saleItem: false }`
I then run `item = { ...item, saleItem: true };` within my effect an fire off the reducer. However this is causing an infinite loop somewhere with `console.log('before', item);` and `console.log('after', item);` being logged out over and over again. Below is the code I have and some alternatives I've tried

Selector

```
export const getBasketEntities = createSelector(
  getBasketState,
  fromItems.getBasketEntities
);

export const getSelectedItem = createSelector(
  getBasketEntities,
  fromRoot.getRouterState,
  (entities, router): Item => {
    return router.state && entities[router.state.params.id];
  }
);
```

Component

```
this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.UpdateItem());
```

Action

```
export class UpdateItem implements Action {
  readonly type = UPDATE_ITEM;
  constructor() {}
}
```

Effects

```
// update effect
@Effect()
updateItem$ = this.actions$.ofType(itemActions.UPDATE_ITEM).pipe(
  switchMap(() => {
    return this.store.select(fromSelectors.getSelectedItem).pipe(
      map((item: Item) => {
        console.log('before', item);
        item = { ...item, saleItem: true };
        console.log('after', item);
        return new itemActions.UpdateItemSuccess(item);
      }),
      catchError(error => of(new itemActions.UpdateItemFail(error)))
    );
  })
);
```

Reducer

```
case fromItems.UPDATE_ITEM_SUCCESS: {
  const item: Item = action.payload;
  console.log('reducer', item);

  const entities = {
    ...state.entities,
    [item.id]: item
  };

  return {
    ...state,
    entities
  };
}
```

**UPDATE:**

- Removed the selector from the effect.
- Calling the selector and passing the value into the action (payload)
- Updating the item in the reducer

This results in the same outcome.

Component

```
onUpdate() {
  this.store
    .select(fromStore.getSelectedItem)
    .pipe(
      map((item: Item) => {
        this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.UpdateItem(item));
      })
    )
    .subscribe()
    .unsubscribe();
```

}

Effect

```
@Effect()
  updateItem$ = this.actions$.ofType(itemActions.UPDATE_ITEM).pipe(
  map((action: itemActions.UpdateItem) => action.payload),
  map((item: Item) => {
    return new itemActions.UpdateItemSuccess(item);
  }),
  catchError(error => of(new itemActions.UpdateItemFail(error)))
);
```

Action

```
export class UpdateItem implements Action {
  readonly type = UPDATE_ITEM;
  constructor(public payload: Item) {}
}
```

Reducer

```
case fromItems.UPDATE_ITEM_SUCCESS: {
  const item: Item = action.payload;

  const entities = {
    ...state.entities,
    [item.id]: { ...item, saleItem: true }
  };
  return {
    ...state,
    entities
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you have an infinite loop:

You subscribe on the selector -> in the effect you create a new ref and modify the item -> you update the state -> this triggers the selectors -> and so on …

To fix this:

- Do not update an item inside your effect.
- Set the selected item as payload in the update action
- Update the item in your reducer (you don't need the success or fail action in your example)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. however that results in the same outcome. I've added an UPDATE of code. Unsubscribing from the selector.

Comment: I added passed an static item object `testItem = { id: 0, product: TV, saleItem: false },`  into the dispatch `this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.UpdateItem(testItem));` which worked ok so it's the selector subscribe which is causing the issue. Even when I use `unsubscribe` on it. And I thought a `switchMap` unsubscribes from itself once it's finished. Hence why I thought i could use the selector within the effect.

Comment: Yea correct, that's what I meant with `Set the selected item as payload in the update action`. You should try to minimize selects on the store in your effects.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with the below, but this doesn't feel good at all.
Preferable I'd just like one line with my dispatch and selector in my effects file.
I've looked into `withLatestFrom()` on my selector for a cleaner solution

UPDATE: Alternatively I found and used the following discussion: [on gihub](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/467) and [stackblitz](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/467). I used Option 2 and replaced `do` with `map`. This means i can run my one line in my component `this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.UpdateItem());` and then set the item replacement in the reducer with `[item.id]: { ...state.entities[item.id], saleItem: true }`

**Initial Fix**

```
this.selectedItem: Item;

onUpdate() {
   this.store
     .select(fromStore.getSelectedItem)
     .subscribe((item: Item) => this.selectedItem = item )
     .unsubscribe();
   this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.UpdateItem(this.selectedItem));
 }
```

**StackBlitz method 1** - replacing `tap` with `map`. Cleaner

```
@Effect()
  updateItem$ = this.actions$.ofType(itemActions.UPDATE_ITEM).pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(fromSelectors.getSelectedItem))),
    map(([type, item]: Array<any>) => {
      console.log('in effect', item);
      return new itemActions.UpdateItemSuccess(item);
    }),
    catchError(error => of(new itemActions.UpdateItemFail(error)))
  );
```